# When running my pip package I get ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a Python program which works great when running it from the src directory E.g.:

```
> python start.py
```

I've published the package to pip, and after I've installed it and running it I get:

```
> microservicebus-py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/microservicebus-py", line 5, in <module>
    from src.start import main
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/src/start.py", line 6, in <module>
    import utils
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'
```

The `utils.py` is in the same directory as the `start.py` file, but I must be missing some setting perhaps in my setup.py used for creating the pip package?

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: `src` is _really_ not a good module name. Try to pick something that won't exist elsewhere by accident. `usvcbus`, for example, is a lot less likely to have random collisions.

Comment: And new versions of Python have moved towards making relative imports explicit; implicit ones were deprecated with Python 3, which is quite a long time ago now. The modern, explicit syntax is `from . import utils`